# Create dynamic where based on array of conditions

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

New to python and working on a query.

Looking to create a dynamic where conditions

What I have is:

```
"attributes": [{
      "code": "grp1",
      "values": ['D','E','F']
   },
   {
      "code": "grp2",
      "values": ['A','B','C']
   }
]
```

Trying to create where condition looks like,

```
WHERE grp1 IN ('D','E','F') AND grp2 IN ('A','B','C')
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `json` library in python to read the file, and the process it as if it was a python `dict`, like in the example below.

Hoping it helps :)

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    query = "WHERE "
    i = 0
    l = len(data["attributes"])
    for sub_dict in data["attributes"]:
        i += 1
        for k, v in sub_dict .items():
            if(k == "code"):
                query += str(v)
            elif (k == "values" and i < l):
                query += " IN " + str(v) + " AND "
            elif (k == "values" and i == l):
                query += " IN " + str(v)
```